# Creating a deadlock

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, c#-4.0, deadlock

I have some code that looks like the below. Does this create a deadlock?

```
private readonly object objectLock = new object();

public void MethodA()
{
    lock(objectLock)
    {
       MethodB();
    }
}

public void MethodB()
{
    lock(objectLock)
    {
      //do something
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** There will 2 threads running

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No its not a deadlock. Its the same thread locking on the same synchronization object. A thread can take nested locks. It just needs to release it equal no. of times.

Comment: What if MethodA called MethodB twice. Would that still be ok?

Comment: Yea it would still be ok. Did you try? A deadlock will hang all your threads involved in deadlock. You can not have a deadlock with a single thread. Do you even have multiple threads in your app?

Comment: @Jon even then it is not going to cause a deadlock. It is the same sync object they're locking on.

Comment: @Jon: `MethodB` is called by `MethodA` in the same thread, of course. Still no deadlock.

Comment: The missing word/term in this conversation is 'Reentrancy' ;-)

Answer (score 11):

No - but this would be:

```
private readonly object objectLockA = new object();
private readonly object objectLockB = new object();

public void MethodA()
{
    lock(objectLockA)
    {
    lock(objectLockB)
    {
       //...
    }
    }
}

public void MethodB()
{
    lock(objectLockB)
    {
    lock(objectLockA)
    {
      //do something
    }
    }
}
```

If you call both Methods in parallel (from 2 different threads) then you would get a deadlock...

Answer (score 3):

No, you'd need two lock objects to enable a deadlock.

Answer (score 3):

If this is the only mutex involved, it isn't. The same thread can lock the same mutex multiple times, as long it unlocks it equal number of times.

Calling `MethodA` produces the following sequence of operations on the same thread:

- Lock `objectLock`.
- Call `MethodB`.
- Lock `objectLock`.
- Unlock `objectLock`.
- Exit `MethodB`.
- Unlock `objectLock`.

So, `objectLock` is locked twice and unlocaked twice, but there is no deadlock:

- If another thread tries to call `MethodA` it will simply block on the first lock but will not deadlock.
- It if calls `MethodB`, the same would happen.
- And if first thread call `MethodB` and then other thread calls `MethodA`, again "normal" blocking would take place but not a deadlock.

Answer (score 1):

If you copy paste the following lines, compile and run see that "never called" is not printed in the console.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace deadlocktest
{
    class Program
    {
    static object object1 = new object();
    static object object2 = new object();

    public static void FunctionOne()
    {
        lock (object1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("FunctionOne called 1");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            lock (object2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("FunctionOne called 2, never called");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void FunctionTwo()
    {
        lock (object2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("FunctionTwo called 1");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            lock (object1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("FunctionTwo called 2, never called");
            }
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Thread thread1 = new Thread(FunctionOne);
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(FunctionTwo);
        thread1.Start();
        thread2.Start();
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 9)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("How bad thread!");
            i++;
        }
        thread1.Join();
        thread2.Join();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}